# Win app driver not working in Selenium Webdriver Typescript

Tags: typescript, winappdriver

Trying to use Win App Driver with Typescript to automate a Windows Desktop App. And when I run the below code in any test framework I get a 400 error in win app driver and I see a error message browser is mandatory eventhough am testing a desktop app.

And when I give a some value for browserName it still gives 400 error in win app driver with error message either app or appLevelTopWindow should be given

app is Root so I can iterate through all available apps. The same approach works with C# Webdriver and with C# as coding language but not working with Typescript with Selenium Webdriver and Selenium Appium

```
const capabilities = {
  platformName: 'Windows',
  deviceName: 'WindowsPC',
  app: 'Root' 
};

await driver.startWithCapabilities(capabilities);
```

Below are libraries used in node js
Selenium-webdriver: 4.18.1
Selenium-appium: 4.1.22